# Как правильно обновлять Python программу с удаленного сервера?

Tags: python, update, pyinstaller

У меня имеется скомпилированная в .exe программа на Python. Она использует множество библиотек, в том числе и графический интерфейс на PyQt5. Я решил не собирать этот проект в один цельный файл и сейчас программа представляет собой набор из 100+ элементов (папки и файлы, *созданные pyinstaller*)

Появилась необходимость периодически обновлять программу. Вместо того, чтобы постоянно переустанавливать ее, пользователю было бы удобнее получать уведомление об обновлении и обновлять прогу с удаленного сервера. Это все уже реализовано.

---

Вопрос в том, что именно нужно качать при обновлении? Какую роль играют файлы, созданные pyinstaller? На данный момент, я обновляю только главный исполняемый файл и он прекрасно работает со старым окружением из .dll и .pyd файлов, хоть я и дописал уже 250+ строк кода и импортировал около 5 новых библиотек.

Все же я боюсь, что в один момент прога может отказаться работать из-за того что не подходит один из файлов окружения. В каком случае такое возможно и возможно ли вообще? Если да, то какие файлы нужно обновлять помимо исполняемого?

Comment: "импортировал около 5 новых библиотек" эти библиотеки это внешние зависимости? как я понимаю все у вас будет прекрасно пока вы не захотите добавить новую внешнюю зависимость или обновить версию какой либо уже установленной. тогда нужно будет разбираться что именно и куда копирует pyinstaller

Comment: Библиотеки, именно то, которые идут вместе с питоном или устанавливаются через pip. Каких-то доп. модулей не использую, все в одном основном файле

Comment: не понял вопроса) бибилиотеки который установлены вместе с питоном у тебя уже упаковыны все. я говорил лишь про те библиотеки который ты через pip ставишь.

Comment: Понял. Видимо стоит заранее проверять и если не работает, стоит просто обновлять весь проект.